# Change antd TreeSelect dropdown item's label text

Tags: reactjs, antd

Normal design for TreeSelect is show only label. But I want to show label and value as label at TreeSelect such as ( value / label ).

```
> 0001 / Jane Maryam
> 0002 / John Wick
> 0005 / David Gue
```

I can change treeData(from an api) with .map and modify label as what i expected but i want to change label  style as ( value / label )  without any data modifications.

Here is my code sample

```
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const {  TreeSelect  } = antd;
const {  useState  } = React;;
const treeData = [
  {
    value: '0001',
    label: 'Jane Maryam',
  },
   {
    value: '0003',
    label: 'John Wick',
  },
    {
    value: '0003',
    label: 'David Gue',
  }
    ]
  
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();
  const onChange = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <TreeSelect
      showSearch
      style={{
        width: '100%',
      }}
      value={value}
      dropdownStyle={{
        maxHeight: 400,
        overflow: 'auto',
      }}
      placeholder="Please select"
      allowClear
      onChange={onChange}
      treeData={treeData}
    />
  );
};
const ComponentDemo = App;


createRoot(mountNode).render(<ComponentDemo />);
```

Is TreeSelect has this feature?

Comment: When you receive data from server, you can map over the list and add one more key `title` in each object. `const data = [].map((item) => ({ ...item, title: `${item.value} / ${item.label}` }));`. Now antd TreeSelect will automatically pick title field and show it in tree instead of label.